# Mongoose error when large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to access a collection with more than a million documents (1281034) through mongoose without success.

I have tried this 3 ways:

Normal access to a whole collection

```
@find({},'_id n').exec (error, value) ->
```

> Mongoose: items.find({}) { fields: { n: 1, _id: 1 } }

With a limit, this works but 99999(Max allowed) limit its not enough

```
@find({},'_id n').limit(99999).exec (error, value) ->
```

> Mongoose: items.find({}) { limit: 99999, fields: { n: 1, _id: 1 } }

With a stream, this also works but gives an out of memory error

```
stream = @find({},'_id n').stream()
stream.on('data', (doc)->
     results.push doc
     console.log "#{results.length}"
    ).on('close', ->
      console.log "Finished : #{results.length}"
    )
```

at 415786 documents it crashes: (FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory)

Comment: Why do you want to put all million+ documents into an in-memory array? There's probably a better way to do what you're ultimately trying to do.

Comment: To cache them in another storage system like redis. @JohnnyHK

Comment: Then why not augment your streaming approach to add the docs to redis as you're receiving them in the `'data'` callback instead of storing them all in the array?

Comment: Yes thats the approach im actually doing, after i finished it i will post the result as response. than you @JohnnyHK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my solution was to avoid storing in memory the million items as the result of the query. The best approach I found is using NodeJS streams so I do not need to use large amounts of memory.

```
stream = @find({}).stream()
stream.on('data', (doc)->
 Redis.push('items',JSON.stringify(doc))
)
```

If you want a more readable way you can also chain the `.pipe()` method and pass it a `writeableStream`.